# Android - HTTP Push with Tomcat (servlets)

Tags: android, http, tomcat, servlets, push

I am trying to push json data from a servlet deployed in Tomcat to my Android app.

I've already checked out the C2DM but I think it requires me to have a working internet connection because the data is pushed from Google servers.

I need the push to be available when connected to an offline network (Wi-Fi). Can this be done? Or maybe anybody can suggest me other options? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [blogpost](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) will help.

Comment: Please read [policy about 'One-Link-Only-Answers'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers) and improve your answer.